# How to calculate geographic distances using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Given a MySQL table with a series of latitude and longitude points, stored as strings, how can I find the distances between each point in the table and a given point, call it "originlat, originlon" ?

I have found numerous post on SO but the values I get from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points popular piece do not even remotely match up to the values I get from online tools, such as Google Maps and this JS based tool: http://www.csgnetwork.com/gpsdistcalc.html

I also read this but it didn't mean much to me: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html